# Importing StartSSL Key

Tags: ssl, certificate

A few months ago I signed up for a Free StartSSL certificate but I didn't realize that you needed to install that certificate if you wanted to later log in to the control panel.

Now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get back in.  On my web server, I've got a `ssl.key` and a `ssl-universal.crt` file.  I've downloaded the `.crt` file, and went through the Windows Certificate Install wizard.  If I go into the Certificate Manager, I can see the certificate under Other People:

[image: Certificate installed]

But I still get the SSL connection error when I try to access the control panel.  I'm not sure what I need to do.

Comment: Are you accessing the control panel from the webserver?  The client cert and key need to be on whatever machine you are going to startssl with.  If you double click that cert above, you should be able to see if it has the private key

Comment: No.  I'm accessing this on my personal computer.  I have a `.key` file, but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Can you double click the cert above and see if it says you have a private key for that cert?  Is that definitely the one for authentication to openssl?

Comment: It doesn't mention anything about a private key in the Details path.  The cert appears to be working fine on the web server https://secure.ianspence.com/.  I'm sure that the .key file I have is for this cert, as I remember installing it a few months back.

Comment: Ah, as I recall, startssl provide you a separate client certificate for logging in.  It is not the same as your website one.

Comment: So I'm pretty much SOL, aren't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have lost your StartSSL client authentication certificate, you can re-register with a different userid (which will give you a new cert), and contact them to associate your account.

From the [FAQ](http://www.startssl.com/?app=25#14):

> 14.) I've lost my client authentication certificate, what shall I do?
>
> Make sure that you are using the same computer and browser you used to
>   register. If you are certain that you've lost the client certificate
>   and you can't login anymore, register once again by using a different
>   email address (if the original certificate hasn't expired yet).
>   Contact the CertMaster with your details and we'll try to associate
>   your new client authentication certificate with your original account.